# Scala inferred least upper bound

Tags: scala, inferred-type

Scala 2.12. The following code

```scala
val mapBuilder = Map.newBuilder[String, String]
val setBuilder = Set.newBuilder[String]

List(Option("")).foreach {
  case Some(_) => mapBuilder += "" -> ""
  case None => setBuilder += ""
}
```

does not compile - compiler fails to infer the least upper bound of the two builders (the `U` in `foreach[U](f: A => U)`):

```
type arguments [String,Iterable[java.io.Serializable] with String => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[String,Equals]] do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds [A,+Repr <: scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[A,Repr]]
```

Annotating the `foreach` with `Any` resolves the problem:

```scala
List(Option("")).foreach[Any] {
...
```

Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: FWIW it compiles on Scala 2.13.